# sapui5 snapshot drawing 2 pics second time and 3 third time

Tags: canvas, sapui5, snapshot

I have code here to open camera and take snapshot and attaching it to canvas. the first time its good and I get one picture. The second time i get 2 pics and third time 3 pics. Where should i change the code to avoid this problem? I am just trying this as a small CRUD operation.

onCapturePics: function(oEvent) {
var that = this;

```
            if(!this.oDefaultDialog) {
                this.oDefaultDialog = new sap.m.Dialog({
                    title: "Click on Capture to take a photo",
                    beginButton: new sap.m.Button({
                        text: "Capture Photo",                      
                    press: function(oEvent){
                        //TODO
                        //take the main page global variable
                        that.imageVal = document.getElementById("player");
                        var oButton = oEvent.getSource();
                        this.imageText = oButton.getParent().getContent()[1].getValue();
                        g_setText = this.imageText;
                        that.oDefaultDialog.close();
                    },

                }),
                content: [
                    
                    new sap.ui.core.HTML({
                        content: "<video id='player' autoplay><video>",         

                    }),   

                    new sap.m.Input({
                        placeholder: "Please input image text here",
                        required: true
                    
                    }),

                ],  
                endButton: new sap.m.Button({
                    text: "Cancel",
                    press:function () {
                        that.oDefaultDialog.close();
                        that.oDefaultDialog.destroy();
                    },
            
                    }),
                        
            });
            // to get access to the controller's model

        }
        this.getView().addDependent(this.oDefaultDialog);
        this.oDefaultDialog.open();          
        //from here
        that.oDefaultDialog.attachBeforeClose(this.setImage,this);
        var oDeviceModel = new JSONModel({
            isPad: sap.ui.Device.system.tablet,
            isDesktop: sap.ui.Device.system.desktop
        });

        //Camera desktop for frontend and back camera for ipad
        if (oDeviceModel.oData.isDesktop) {
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({   // eslint-disable-line
            video: true
            }).then((stream) => {
                player.srcObject = stream;      // eslint-disable-line
            });

        //that.oDefaultDialog.attachBeforeClose(this.setImage, this);   
        } 
        else {
            navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({   // eslint-disable-line
                //video: true
                video: {
                    facingMode: 'environment'
                  }
                }).then((stream) => {
                    player.srcObject = stream;      // eslint-disable-line
                });

        //  that.oDefaultDialog.attachBeforeClose(this.setImage,this);  
        }           
        },
        
    setImage:function(){
            //Take the running Image from the video stream of the camera
            //set it like canvas element on HTML page
        var Order = this.getView().getModel("appModel").getProperty("/returnOrderDetails"); 
        var oVBox = sap.ui.getCore().byId("vBox1");
         var items = oVBox.getItems();          
         var snapId = 'Returns-' + items.length;
         var textId = Order[g_row].Batch + "-" + Order[g_row].NdcNo + "-" + Order[g_row].Material + "-" + g_setText;
         var imageVal = this.imageVal;
         //if (imageVal == null){
        //  MessageToast.show("No Image Captured");
            
        // } else {
         var oCanvas = new sap.ui.core.HTML({
            content: "<canvas id='" + snapId +"' width='320px' height='320px' "+
                            "style='2px solid red'></canvas> " +
                            "<label text='"+ textId +"'>" + textId +"</label>" 
                    
         });

         var snapShotCanvas;    
         var imagearray = [];
         oVBox.addItem(oCanvas,imagearray);
         this.getView().getModel("appModel").setProperty("/itemImage", imagearray);
         oCanvas.addEventDelegate({
            onAfterRendering: function() {
                snapShotCanvas = document.getElementById(snapId);
                var oContext = snapShotCanvas.getContext('2d');
                oContext.drawImage(imageVal,0,0, snapShotCanvas.clientWidth, snapShotCanvas.height);
                
                g_fileName = textId;
                //g_stringImage = document.getElementById("Returns-0");
                  g_stringImage = document.getElementById("Returns-0").toDataURL().replace("data:image/png;base64,","");
                  imagearray.push({
                    Image: g_stringImage,
                    ImageName : g_setText
                    });
                  g_stringImage = '';
                  g_setText = '';
            }
         });            
        //}
        },
```

Fragment calling the dialog :


-->

I try to take one picture and first time it comes good. but second time it takes 2 pictures and third time 3 pics.